# How do I hide Devel tab from users?

Tags: debugging

I just noticed that Devel tabs are showing on my Basic Pages, even when the user is not logged in. Anonymous users should not see "View" and "Devel" tabs! I can't find a setting for this in the Devel configuration page. Any ideas how to prevent the tabs from displaying? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Duh... It isn't the Devel config that controls it. It's the "Access developer information" permission. Someone had turned it on for anonymous users. Doh!